# How not to request for sidebar elements if the sidebar is not visible

Tags: html, web-performance

Let's imagine a blog.

For example: https://around.createx.studio/blog-grid-rs.html

Here we can see that there is a content area and a sidebar. The sidebar is not visible at narrow screens. In other words it exists, but is not visible.

We can clearly reveal it by example of an image. Let's concentrate on that image of a girl with virtual reality glasses. That is image th01.jpg.

[image]
[image]

If there is no sidebar, th01.jpg is loaded all the same.

I'd like to get rid of it. A sidebar may really be heavely burdened with images or something. It may contain advertising scripts etc. If a sidebar is not visible, it would be a huge boost in performance if we just don't request a server for its elements.

Could you tell me how to avoid the requests for sidebar elements if the sidebar is not visible? I'd like a complete list of such means even if I'm not able to use them. I just want to know all of them even if I use only one.

Answer (score 0):

If you can receive your sidebar data in request:

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => result.forEach((el) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = el.thumbnailUrl;
    img.onload = function() {
        wrapper.append(img);
    };
  }))
```

Comment: There are a lot of stuff in the sidebar. Not only images. There are advertising scripts, that are pretty slow and burdensome. Embedding of video and instagram posts. They are all very slow. Is there any other ideas?